# Strange behaviour of optionals in Swift 3

Tags: json, swift3, option-type

I have experienced a strange behaviour when parsing JSON data using Swift 3.

```
do {
  let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! NSDictionary
  let items:[AnyObject] = (json["items"] as? [AnyObject])!
  for item in items {
    let id:String = item["id"] as! String
    print("ID: \(id)")
    let info = item["volumeInfo"] as AnyObject
    print(info)
    let title = info["title"]
    print(title)
  }
} catch {
  print("error thrown")
}
```

This produces the following output. Notice that info is an optional but if I try to unwrap it it states it is not an optional! The script crashes on `let title = info["title"]` As a result I can't access the title key. This behaviour has changed since Swift 2.

```
ID: lbvUD6LUyV8C
Optional({
  publishedDate = 2002;
  publisher = "Sams Publishing";
  title = "Java Deployment with JNLP and WebStart";
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
do {
    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! [String: Any]
    let items = json["items"] as! [[String: Any]]
    for item in items {
        let id = item["id"] as! String
        let info = item["volumeInfo"] as! [String: Any]
        let title = info["title"] as! String

        print(id)
        print(info)
        print(title)
    }
} catch {
    print("error thrown: \(error)")
}
```

I might suggest excising the code of the `!` forced unwrapping (if the JSON was not in the form you expected, do you really want this to crash?), but hopefully this illustrates the basic idea.

Answer (score 0):

The runtime type of `info` is `Optional<Something>`, but the compile time type (as you explicitly cast it) is `AnyObject`. How is the compiler supposed to know that the `AnyObject` will happen to be an `Optional<Something>` unless you tell it (in the form of a cast)?

Try:

```
let info = item["volumeInfo"] as AnyObject?
```

Now the compiler knows it's an `Optional<AnyObject>`, so you can unwrap it.

Comment: Tried your solution but now when I print `info` I get `Optional(Optional({
    publishedDate = "2011-12-28";
    publisher = "Jones & Bartlett Publishers";
    title = "Programming with Java: A Multimedia Approach";
}))`

Comment: If you post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I'll be more than happy to troubleshoot this with you.

Comment: Emphasis on **minimal**

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3 the compiler must know the types of all subscripted objects if it's an array or dictionary. `AnyObject` – which has been changed to `Any` in Swift 3 – is not sufficient.

Since you know that the value for key `volumeInfo` is a dictionary cast it accordingly preferably using optional bindings

```
let info = item["volumeInfo"] as? [String:Any] {
   print(info)
   let title = info["title"] as! String
   print(title)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
guard let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! [String: AnyObject],
    let items = json["items"] as! Array<AnyObject>? else {
    return
}

for item in items {
    let id = item["id"] as! String
    if let info = item["volumeInfo"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
        let title = info["title"] as! String
    } else {
        // do something
    }
}
```